# Use date field from MongoDB list as DatetimeIndex in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am reading in data from a MongoDB collection

```
mongo_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = client.db
collection = db.coll
docs = list(collection.find({}, {"Date": 1, "Cost" : 1, "_id" : 0 }).sort("date", pymongo.ASCENDING))
```

so I end up with an list of dicts stored in docs, of the form

```
[{u'Date': u'2008-01-01', u'Cost': 8557.0}, {u'Date': u'2008-01-02', u'Cost': 62307.0},.....]
```

I can then create a `DataFrame` from this

```
frame = DataFrame(docs)
```

which is of the form

[image]

but I want the *Date* column to be used as a `DatetimeIndex`. I have been doing this in a pretty hacky way but I know there must be a cleaner way of doing this.

```
frame = frame.set_index(pd.to_datetime(frame['Date']))
```

[image]

Also, if I examine the index I see that the `freq` is not present, so I want to try and set the daily frequency when creating the `DataFrame`

[image]

---

### Update

@jezrael replied with an excellent answer so I just wanted to explain here which approach worked for me.

If I try this

```
frame = DataFrame(docs)
frame.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
frame.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(frame.index, freq='D')
```

for some reason I get the following error

> ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed dates does notconform
>   to passed frequency D

but the other suggestion works great for me.

```
idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in docs], freq='D')
frame = DataFrame(docs, index=idx)
frame = frame.drop('Date', 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need create `Datetimindex` in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
docs = [{u'Date': u'2008-01-01', u'Cost': 8557.0},{u'Date': u'2008-01-02', u'Cost': 62307.0}]

idx =  pd.DatetimeIndex([x['Date'] for x in docs], freq='D')
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

frame = pd.DataFrame(docs, index=idx)
print (frame)
               Cost        Date
2008-01-01   8557.0  2008-01-01
2008-01-02  62307.0  2008-01-02

print (frame.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Another solution, if create `DatetimeIndex` after creating `DataFrame`:

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
docs = [{u'Date': u'2008-01-01', u'Cost': 8557.0},{u'Date': u'2008-01-02', u'Cost': 62307.0}]
frame = pd.DataFrame(docs)
print (frame)
      Cost        Date
0   8557.0  2008-01-01
1  62307.0  2008-01-02

frame.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
frame.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(frame.index, freq='D')
print (frame)
               Cost
2008-01-01   8557.0
2008-01-02  62307.0

print (frame.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

If need copy column `Date` to `index`:

```
docs = [{u'Date': u'2008-01-01', u'Cost': 8557.0},{u'Date': u'2008-01-02', u'Cost': 62307.0}]
frame = pd.DataFrame(docs)
print (frame)
      Cost        Date
0   8557.0  2008-01-01
1  62307.0  2008-01-02

frame.set_index(frame.Date, inplace=True)
frame.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(frame.index, freq='D')
print (frame)
               Cost        Date
2008-01-01   8557.0  2008-01-01
2008-01-02  62307.0  2008-01-02
print (frame.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```